# IIS 7.5 returns 404 on existing PHP file

Tags: windows, php, iis, windows-7, iis-7

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler PHP54_via_FastCGI
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/phpinfo.php
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

I followed the following guide:
[http://www.landpro.com.au/Windows_7_Install_IIS_7_&*PHP*&_FastCGI.php](http://www.landpro.com.au/Windows_7_Install_IIS_7_&_PHP_&_FastCGI.php)

Permissions:

[image]

What am I doing wrong to be getting this error?

EDIT: I now see the .txt at the end... stupid Microsoft default settings.. UGH

Comment: That error code is `file not found`. Are permissions set correctly?

Comment: That was my first thought when it comes to working with PHP on Apache I've seen that but I think I have them correct. Uploading a picture.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. Had to disable that stupid hide known file extension setting to remove the hidden .txt.

I hate stupid settings like that....